# How can I install Electrum on 32-bit Windows?

Tags: electrum, windows, installation

So on the Electrum site in the download section for Windows 7 Pro there is no reference to 32 or 64 bit? I need a desktop version in 32-bit?

Answer (score 1):

Electrum is an elaborate python script.  It uses the same bitwidth as your python interpreter.  If you have Py32 installed it is 32 bit, if you have Py64 it is 64 bit.

#### For windows users

The standalone EXE is 32-bit.  If you need to run 64-bit in PE or some other non WoW environment, simple grab the python libraries from the site and run the python sources at 64 bit.

```
PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               6 number of sections
        597F4AD5 time date stamp Mon Jul 31 10:20:53 2017
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
             122 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   32 bit word machine
```

For more on windows EXE bitwidth, check [this answer by Richard](https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows)

Comment: Thank you...if any one sees this there is a windows installer and also a stand alone installer that is for 32 bit windows 7.